# Confused why returnPartialData works without a field policy in Apollo Client 3

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

In my application I am searching for products, then clicking into a product to see more detail about it.

I perform a GraphQL query on each page. The `SEARCH` query returns type `[Product]`, and the `PRODUCT` query returns type `Product`.

```
// Search page
const SEARCH = gql`
  query Search($query: String!) {
    searchResults: search(query: $query) {
      id
      name
      images
      price
    }
  }
`

// ProductDetail page
const PRODUCT = gql`
  query Product($id: Int!) {
    product(id: $id) {
      id
      name
      images
      optionSetName
      options {
        id
        images
        name
      }
      price
    }
  }
`
```

I have enabled [returnPartialData](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#returnpartialdata) on the `PRODUCT` query, as some of the fields for that product already exist in the cache from the `SEARCH` query, and I would like to access them before the server request returns.

I thought I would also have to [apply a field policy](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/#cache-redirects) to reference the pre-existing `Product`, as I don't know how `PRODUCT` even knows what its return type is.

However, when I do the following:

```
const { loading, data: { product } = {} } = useQuery(
    PRODUCT,
    { variables: { id: productId, isShallow }, returnPartialData: true }
)
console.log(product)
```

the following is logged to console (the first is from `returnPartialData`, the second from server):

[image: console]

Somehow the `PRODUCT` query has associated itself with the existing `Product`, without me explicitly writing a cache redirect.

I'm confused how this has occurred? It seems like Apollo must have a reference to the GraphQL schema, and has seen the return type of `PRODUCT` is `Product`, then automatically used the `id` arg to reference the existing product.

Using `"@apollo/client": "^3.4.1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, turns out I had made a field policy ages ago and forgotten about it... xD

```
    typePolicies: {
      Query: {
        fields: {
          product: {
            read (_, { args, toReference }) {
              return toReference({
                __typename: 'Product',
                id: args.id
              })
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```